# How can a child take max height without overflowing parent?

Tags: css

I'm working on a navigation bar and I want each `<li>` to be the maximum height available just like `display: block` does.

Comment: well, apply `display:block` or `display:inline-block`. but apply to `ul li{display:/*any display*/}`

Comment: None worked. Can you be specific? Wich one do you recommend and how is it supposed to work?

Comment: show the code, block or inline-block make the text as block, so you can add attributes like width and height

Comment: The `<li>` already is a block, I already specified the with and height. I think I wasn't clear for you. I want the `<li>` to take the maximum height available, without knowing how much there are. I'm sorry, this probably isn't possible.

Comment: `height:100%` maybe would work

Comment: That doesn't work, the `<li>` takes 100% height of the `<ul>`. Wich is in a navigation bar the full screen height. So each `<li>` would be 100 view height. Just forget about it, it's impossible.